# Combinatorial Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, infinite-combinatorics

Any closed subspace $V\subset {\ell}^2(\omega)$ has associated to it a subset ${\cal S}_V$ of ${\cal P}(\omega)$, call it a *combinatorial Hilbert space*, namely the set of all supports of all vectors in $V$.

My question: Can one give a combinatorial characterization of combinatorial Hilbert spaces?

To start things off, I'll mention obvious (or at least nearly obvious) necessary conditions on an ${\cal S}_V$:

1) Closure under countable (and thus here arbitrary) unions [*countable* anticipates generalization to larger ordinals than $\omega$];

2) For sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in {\cal S}_V$ with none contained in the union of all the others, and at least $n-1$ integers belonging to at least two $(A_i)$'s, there exists non-empty $\ C\subsetneq \bigcup A_i$ with $|C|\geq n-1$ such that  $\bigcup A_i\setminus C\in {\cal S}_V$;

3) For $A,B \in {\cal S}_V$ with $\emptyset \not= B \subsetneq A$, there exists non-empty $C\subset B$ with $A\setminus C \in {\cal S}_V$.

.

Comment: There are uncountable families of subsets of $\omega$, so your «and thus here arbitrary» needs some justification, no?

Comment: @Mariano: yes, but if a subset of $\omega$ is the union of a collection of subsets of $\omega$, then it is in fact the union of countably many of them, since $\omega$ itself is countable.

Comment: Now, is that provable in ZF?

Comment: @Ricky No, see
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0806/0806.1957v1.pdf
for example.  An infinite Dedekind finite set of reals would
contain no countable sequence at all.

Comment: Is the collection of finite and cofinite subsets of $\omega$ a combinatorial Hilbert space?  In the analogous question for $\ell^\infty(\omega)$ you can obviously get all subalgebras of $\mathcal P(\omega)$, but here this is not clear at all.   

Comment: > Is the collection of finite and cofinite subsets of ω a combinatorial Hilbert space?

If you have all the finite subsets, you have all the singleton subsets, so you have a basis, and you get all of $\ell^2(\omega)$,
including many subsets neither finite nor cofinite.

You could ask about all the cofinite subset of $\omega$.  Off the top of my head (sketch) generate a subspace by $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ with each $v_i$ having full support but decreasing *much* more rapidly then all the previous. 

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I missed the point that since you are looking at closed subspaces you practically get closure under countably infinite sums.  

Comment: @Stefan  Please explain your remark about ℓ∞(ω). 